# One custom loop with condition to check child posts

Tags: loop, conditional-content

I have one loop of pages with 999 page ID as a parent (pages from this loop have also another child pages)

```
$args = array( 
'post_type' => 'page',
'post_parent' => 999,
'order' => 'ASC',
'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Now I want to get the pages, but with condition, when the page in the loop have child pages I would like to display another structure.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
       <?php if (condition if current post have subpages ) : ?>
            //  html structure, 
       <?php else : ?>
            // another default structure
       <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I've tried with get_page_children, but with no success, I need only the proper condition. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriately named `get_children()` should be what you want.

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    $loop->the_post();
    $args = array(
      'post_parent' => get_the_ID(), // the ID from your loop
      'post_type'   => 'page', 
      'posts_per_page' => 1, // you only need to know if you have children so one is enough
      'post_status' => 'publish' 
    );
    $c = get_children($args);

    if (!empty($c)) {
      //  html structure, 
    } else {
      // another default structure
    }
  }
}
```

If you have more than a few posts in this loop you are going to be running a lot of queries on the page. You should consider caching the results.